# How to access cart total from js file in magento 2?

Tags: cart, mini-cart, magento2.3.3

I want to access the cart total from js. I have **minicart-mixin.js** in my custom module. I want to get the cart total there.

My file is minicart-mixin.js below.

```
define([
'uiComponent',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'jquery',
'ko',
'underscore',
'sidebar',
'mage/translate',
'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
'use strict';

var mixin = {
    isButtonEnable: function () {
        /*You can add your condition here based on your requirements.*/
        console.log(customerData.get('cart')._latestValue.subtotal);
    }
};

return function (target) {
    return target.extend(mixin);
};
});
```

Console i am getting like this

```
<span class="price">$70.00</span>
```

How can i get the $70 only.

Comment: do you want cart subtotal, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to try the following solutions.

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
], function (Component,totals) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        getSubTotal: function(){
            if (totals.totals()) {
                var subtotal = parseFloat(totals.totals()['subtotal']);
                return subtotal;
            }
        },

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. and very sorry for late response. I got the value as customerData.get('cart')._latestValue.subtotalAmount.

Comment: @Dhiren how can i put a condition if subtotal is greater than 100 display an element

Comment: @VinitKumar can you please raised separate question and give me link, so other community member also help you.